# за диалоговым окном, макет отображается белым цветом, но сам макет не является белым, подскажите пожалйуюста как решить эту проблему

Tags: java, android

[image: за диалоговым окном, макет отображается белым цветом]

```
<style name="my_dialog"parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog<item 

        <item name="DialogTitleText">Bakı havası yüklənir...</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#ecd30e</item>
        <item name="android:background">#231a35</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">italic</item>
        <item name="DialogSpotColor">#ecd30e</item>
        <item name="DialogSpotCount">5</item>

    </style>

 //----------------------------------------------------


<RelativeLayout

    android:id="@+id/id_bu_gun"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#231a35"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
```

Comment: sene developer deyenin atasina lenet

Comment: Spectr (ayib olsun)

Comment: bilmemek gunah deyil, seni kimi tengidci olmaq ashagiligdir